# Firebase getting data from database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

so my database is as follows

```
   Program1
     Posts:
       PostsID1:
          Name: John
          Age: 12
          User_Id: nv4h8fh4uen8h8f4ufn
       PostsID2
          Name: Don
         ......
```

I have the user Id for the user, how can i check if that user has post in the database and if he does just return his post rather than all the posts. 
For example // nv4h8fh4uen8h8f4ufn is user id.. he has a post so it will return  John,  12,

Comment: Did you try anything yet? The [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start) and [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-ios-swift/) are pretty good to learn basics such as this.

Comment: I think orderbychild would fix this.. I will give it a try now

Comment: Please post the snapshot to your firebase for refrence like [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1b0Z.png) and create [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example

Comment: This task is can be done through a Firebase Query (or other mens) but we don't know what language you're programming in so it's hard to answer.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know if I understood right but, the most common is use the users id as a key, and with that generate child keys for his posts, like this:

```
 Users:
   nv4h8fh4uen8h8f4ufn1:
      Name: John
      Age: 12
      Posts:
         idPost1:
              postData
         idPost2:
              postData
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer is unrelated to the question; the OP wants to know how to retrieve data from their existing Firebase structure, not how to structure a users node.

Comment: with that structure he may be enable to retrieve his data

Comment: That structure is totally unrelated to retrieving a posts node from Firebase and he's already using the uid to tie the user to a post. Maybe you can update your answer to show the relationship or perhaps post some code to show how it relates to the question.